# C++ How can I get my program to display value instead of memory location?

Tags: c++

I have a c++ program that is supposed to read data from a file into an array. Once the array is set up, the user inputs a row number they want displayed and the program is supposed to display the value stored in that row. The program successfully reads the data into the array but  it doesn't display the value stored in the row, instead it displays the memory location. Here is the code I wrote:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
 ifstream SeatPrices;
 static const int NUM_ROWS = 15;
 static const int NUM_SEATS = 30;
 string SeatStructures[NUM_ROWS][NUM_SEATS];
 double price[NUM_ROWS];
 int rowRequested;

  SeatPrices.open("SeatPrices.dat"); 
  if (!SeatPrices)
    cout << "Error opening SeatPrices data file.\n";
  else
  {
    for (int rows = 0; rows < NUM_ROWS; rows++)
    {
        SeatPrices >> price[NUM_ROWS];
        cout << endl << "Row " << (rows + 1) << ":\t";
        cout << "$" << price[NUM_ROWS];
    }
    cout << endl << endl;
  }
  SeatPrices.close();

  cout << "In which row would you like to find seats(1 - 15)? ";
  cin >> rowRequested;
  cout << fixed << showpoint << setprecision(2);
  cout << "Price per seat: $" << price[rowRequested] << endl;

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: `SeatPrices >> price[NUM_ROWS];` writes past the end of the array. You want `SeatPrices >> price[i];`

Comment: @Johnny And similar elsewhere.

Comment: You may want to familiarize yourself with the debugger. It would have saved you a lot of time.

Comment: @ Raymond Chen I am familiar with the debugger and it didn't show any error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you're reading all the data from the file into `price[NUM_ROWS]`, which is one past the end of the array.  Since you immediately `cout` this value, it'll look like the program is working.  You probably want to read values into `price[rows]`.

Comment: Yeah, that was the problem. Thanks for your help